# select option with Angular and .net core

Tags: angularjs, .net-core

I have angular controller for get and post some data.
I made two controller to work correctly and now when I made 3rd one with mixing two previous controllers get and post doesn't work. Could you help to find a problem ?
Here is a code.
sparePartController.js
//sparePartController.js

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular.module("app")
        .controller("sparePartController", sparePartController);

    function sparePartController($http)
    {
        var vm = this;

        vm.spareParts = [];

        vm.newSparePart = {};

        vm.errorMessage = "";

        vm.isBusy = true;

        $http.get("/spares/getAll")
            .then(function (response) {
                //success
                angular.copy(response.data, vm.spareParts);
            }, function (error) {
                vm.errorMessage = error;
            }).finally(function () {
                vm.isBusy = false;

            });

        vm.addSparePart = function () {

            vm.isBusy = true;

            vm.errorMessage = "";
            $http.post("/spares", vm.newSparePart)
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log("test");
                    vm.spareParts.push(response.data);
                    vm.newSparePart = {};
                }, function () {
                    console.log = "failed to save new spare";
                    vm.errorMessage = "failed to save new spare";
                }).finally(function () {
                    vm.isBusy = false;

                });

        };
    }
})();
```

Index.cshtml to show spare parts and add new one

```
@model IEnumerable<RnD.Models.ViewModels.SparePartViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Spare Parts List";
}

@section scripts{
    <script src="~/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/sparePartController.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/spareTypeController.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/machineController.js"></script>

}

<div class="row" ng-app="app" ng-controller="sparePartController as vm">
    <!-- Start Modal-->
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Create New Spare Part
    </button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form novalidate name="newSpareForm" ng-submit="vm.addSparePart()">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="InternalCode">Internal Code</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Internal Code" id="InternalCode" ng-model="vm.newSparePart.internalCode" required min="3" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" ng-controller="machineController as machineVM">
                            <label>Machine Type</label>
                            <select class="form-control" ng-model="machineVM.machineType" ng-options="machine.name for machine in machineVM.machines"></select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" ng-controller="spareTypeController as spareVM">
                            <label>Spare Type</label>
                            <select class="form-control" ng-model="spareVM.id">
                                <option ng-repeat="spare in spareVM.spares" value="{{spare.id}}">{{spare.name}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-success" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Modal-->

    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="spare in vm.spareParts">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            {{spare.internalCode}} //it was vm.internalCode
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">

        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S. To add, when I want to post I have problem to catch value from select. Internal code is recognized from angular controller but machinetype it is not recognized that filed always is null.

here is modelview class

```
public class SparePartViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string InternalCode { get; set; }

        [StringLength(4096)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string NameOnFolder { get; set; }

        public decimal? Enter { get; set; }

        public decimal? Exit { get; set; }

        public decimal? Thickness { get; set; }

        public string Band { get; set; }

        public string Color { get; set; }

        public bool Elastic { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public MachineType MachineType { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual SpareType SpareType { get; set; }

    }
```

I even try in index.cshtml to put this code `<select class="form-control" ng-model="vm.newSparePart.machineType" ng-options="machine.name for machine in machineVM.machines"></select>` but in this case when I call [From Body] my viewModel is null

Here is my SparePartsController.cs

```
[Route("/spares")]
    [Authorize]
    public class SparePartsController : Controller
    {
        private ILogger<SparePartsController> _logger;
        private ISparePartRepository _repository;

        public SparePartsController(ISparePartRepository repository, ILogger<SparePartsController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _repository = repository;
        }

        [HttpGet("")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet("getAll")]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            try
            {
                var results = _repository.GetAllSpares();

                return Ok(Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SparePartViewModel>>(results));

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Failed to get all Spares : {ex}");
                return BadRequest("Error Occurred");
            }
        }

        [HttpPost("")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]SparePartViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var newSpare = Mapper.Map<SparePart>(viewModel);

                _repository.AddSpare(newSpare);
                if (await _repository.SaveChangesAsync())
                {
                    return Created($"spare/{newSpare.InternalCode}", Mapper.Map<SparePartViewModel>(newSpare));
                }
            }
            return BadRequest("Failed to save spare.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I update my code, I solve to show data. But still need help to find what is problem on posting.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few things off here. 1. I don't think /spares is the full URL to the add method. 2. Even if it were, you still need to send it a correct signature - i.e. the items within the object you send need to match with items in the add spares method signature. 3. I don't see where your newSparePart object is getting assigned values; it's just an empty object. Share the method signature for your add spare method so we can verify that the serialized object. Which brings up 4. You likely need to serialize your object to json: JSON.stringify(vm.newSparePart) when you send it via HTTP post.

Comment: Url is correct. Your not correct newSparePart is not emtpy object during the posting only at beginning .
When you call http promise and send data it is linking with ng-model and should post with values.

Comment: It looks like SparePartViewModel requires Elastic, MachineType, and SpareType. I don't see where your angular model is getting populated with this ... also - have you tried serializing your data before sending it via your post?

Comment: When I come across a situation like this, I simplify the problem. Create a side project with a basic, simple "SimpleViewModel" that has a string "SimpleCode" and nothing else. Set up your POST method in the .NET controller, and in your angular service. Create an angular controller that contains a prepopulated model to send to the service and have it send with a simple HTML button. Once you get that to work, add a non-nullable "int" variable to your "SimpleViewModel" and add in the necessary value to your angular model and try again, etc.. Eventually you'll get an "aha" moment.

Comment: Other fields are not required as you can see from Entity. Only Mandatory fields are Internal code and last virtual fields. I will as you said to simplify, thats i not a problem. My question is how to populate virtual property from angular and why is not working with my method, what is wrong ?

Comment: I manage to fill all fields from SparePartViewModel and only problem to catch values is for MachineType and SpareType, all other fields are working.